# Why CreateSolidBrush returns random number instead of constant number in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, random

Here is my code :

```
    int clrresult = (int)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 30, 40));
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << clrresult;
    Edit_SetText(CLtbx,wss.str().c_str());
```

every time , I clicked on button , it return rand number with 10 length like this : 1341117845

but the color of the background window is the same. why this happened ?

Why CreateSolidBrush returns random number instead of constant number ?

Thanks.

Comment: [it's an `HBRUSH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183518(v=vs.85).aspx) not an `int`, handles are usually pointers.

Comment: Roughly for the same reason that `(int)(new int(42))` would produce a different value every time it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the MSDN documentation, CreateSolidBrush returns an HBRUSH object, which is a handle to a brush, not a meaningful value. You aren't meant to use the numerical value of it directly. It's essentially a pointer to the actual brush object which is managed by Windows.